# why won't this .htaccess rewrite rule work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use a Wordpress plugin that an update has changed the URL path of linked image pages from ?cpis_image=name_of_image to /cpis_image/name_of_image.

I added this line to my .htaccess (which I have checked is being used)

```
RewriteRule ^/cpis_image/(.*)/$ ?cpis_image=$1 [R=301]
```

but it does not rewrite the new URLs

Testing URLs

```
http://fionascottwilson.co.uk/cpis_image/wood-mouse-with-rasberries/
```

does not become

```
http://fionascottwilson.co.uk/?cpis_image=wood-mouse-with-rasberries
```

- if it did - all would again work after the update.

Can not see what is wrong with the regular expression?

The entire Wordpress section of the .htaccess

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/cpis_image/(.*)$ ?cpis_image=$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: mistake to put in the leading / -- it works when the RewriteRule ^/cpis_image/(.*) looks like RewriteRule ^cpis_image/(.*)$ - apache is not looking at the full URL, but rewriting the part after the domain only.

Comment: Have you tried removing the inital forward slash from the rule?

Comment: Looks like you should have the ? before the $ in > RewriteRule ^/cpis_image/(.*)$ ?cpis_image=$1 [R=301] > (.*)$ ?cpis_image

Comment: yes - that fixed it.  moment of blindness it seems.

Comment: also, I do not need the [R=301] as it is only rewriting the URL and Wordpress then accepts the URL without a need for a Redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try...

```
RewriteRule ^cpis_image/(.*)/$ ?cpis_image=$1 [R=301]
```